# @Column(nullable=false) validating the null check at application level

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

From my understanding nullable = false(let say for column customerid) is only useful for creating schemas using hibernate and it should not do any kind of validation before persisting. My database column has no such constraint(it can take null values), while persisting the entity with customerid null, getting this error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value :b
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at
```

This error started keep coming after i update my spring boot version to 2.4.2

Entity class

```
public class FaceIndexResponse extends AuditEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="customer_id",nullable = false)
    private String customerId;
    @Column(name="application_id")
    private String appid;}
```

Service class where i was trying to save the above entity

```
public IndexFacesResult handle(FaceIndexModel model) throws IOException{
    FaceIndexResponse response=new FaceIndexResponse();
    response.setAppid(model.getApplicationId);
    faceIndexResponseJpa.save(response);
 }


                                   Table "public.face_index_response"
     Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |             Default              
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 id             | integer                     |           | not null | generated by default as identity
 customer_id    | character varying(64)       |           |          | 
 application_id | character varying(64)       |           |          |
```

Comment: can you share the code from which this exception is thrown?

Comment: i was trying to save the entity using springJpa where customerid was null.

Comment: have you check the database table? Reconfirm that the column is nullable in database. Make sure to refresh any database client window you have already opened.

Comment: yes column in database table does not contain any constraints.

Comment: Strange. I always assumed this was how it was supposed to work: That the DB abstraction layer enforced it so you didn’t have to have a column constraint

Comment: If the property is supposed to accept `null`s and there's no DB constraint, why did you use `nullable = false` in the first place?

Comment: @crizzis this is an old project, there are lot of instances like this in the codebase, so i dont want to manually remove nullable=false from every place.

Comment: @NubMaster how hard can it be to globally replace `, nullable = false` with a blank using an editor?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a change in Spring Boot 2.3.x:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters

> As of #19550, Web and WebFlux starters do not depend on the validation starter by default any more. If your application is using validation features, for example you find that `javax.validation.*` imports are not being resolved, you’ll need to add the starter yourself.

As of 2.3.0, the Validation starter is no longer included in the Web starters. That means that Bean Validation is no longer on the classpath, causing a change in Hibernate's behaviour. This is indicated in the Hibernate docs here:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_bean_validation_options

> hibernate.check_nullability (e.g. true or false)
> Enable nullability checking. Raises an exception if a property marked as not-null is null.

> Default to false if Bean Validation is present in the classpath and Hibernate Annotations is used, true otherwise.

So, the sudden validation taking place can be resolved in two ways:

- By setting `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.check_nullability` to `false` as indicated in PDiddly's answer
- Or by adding the `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency to your project:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

(or the individual dependencies for bean validation if you prefer so)

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment above (rep isn't high enough), and there's not enough to know that this will answer the question, but
Take a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-notnull-vs-nullable and https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/appendices/Configurations.html
If you have this set, Hibernate will check null before the DB.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.check_nullability
```

So I'm thinking you have that property set.

Comment: hey thanks, but i already tried this. and there is no such property in my config file.
Earlier it was working fine but the the spring boot upgrade also hibernate version, this is issue has come

Comment: Do you have have Hibernate Validators enabled?
From SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder (Hibernate core)

    this.checkNullability = cfgService.getSetting( CHECK_NULLABILITY, BOOLEAN, true );

And from TypeSafeActivator

    // de-activate not-null tracking at the core level when Bean Validation is present unless the user explicitly
    // asks for it
    if ( cfgService.getSettings().get( Environment.CHECK_NULLABILITY ) == null ) {
 
 
 
 activationContext.getSessionFactory().getSessionFactoryOptions().setCheckNullability( false );
    }